# Android Studio getting class not found exception on connecting database

Tags: java, android, postgresql, android-studio, android-layout

I am connecting to PostgreSQL using JDBC in Android Studio. I have downloaded latest versions of driver and added in libs folder. I added JAR as library and added to dependency. I have added all internet permission and gave port no 5432 and IPV4 address of my laptop while connecting to my mobile. But, I am getting errors  in classloader.java file as java Lang Management Factory not found, etc. I am debugging the same from 72 hours but I didn't got the resolution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCkCm.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QtiW.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd244.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvHx1.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC4fQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dVcb.jpg)

Comment: AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.Managem
entFactory" on path: DexPathList

Comment: Please include the complete error message in the question itself, not in the comments. Edit the question and include it.

Comment: String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://222.222.0.123:5432/Test";
        String username = "postgres";
        String password ="postgres";
        
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Connection conn = null;
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

Comment: There is an edit button there, please click it and add the code, error messages, etc. in the question itself.

Comment: @kiner_shah added images first one error second and third code followed by gradle and manifest last jdbc driver

Comment: Don't post code, error messages as images. Copy and paste them into the post.

Comment: when I am adding it into post, it is saying wrong alignment formatting etc and ts taking too much time to format so posted as images

Comment: and images are totaly visible as it is captured using snipping tool

Comment: Please [reconsider using JDBC in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).

Comment: @CommonsWare but if Iwant to do quickly  because I dont know web service

Comment: @Piyush068, you can use online code formatting tools to format your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that latest version of JAR was not compatible with Android. I worked fine when I used some older version of driver.